# How do I set up key bindings for modes in a specific Evil state?

Tags: key-bindings, evil, web-mode, php-mode

I have a set of key bindings that I use for both `web-mode` and `php-mode` in insert mode (of Evil). So I cannot use `set-local-map` or something. Because in normal mode, the same keys will then call other commands. So the bindings need to be active in `evil-insert-state-map` only.

I have the following:

```el
(eval-after-load 'php-mode
  '(progn
     (define-key evil-insert-state-map
       (kbd "C-<next>") (lambda () (interactive) (insert " = ")))
     (define-key evil-insert-state-map
       (kbd "C-<prior>") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "->")))))

(eval-after-load 'web-mode
  '(progn
     (define-key evil-insert-state-map
       (kbd "C-<next>") 'zencoding-expand-yas) 
     (define-key evil-insert-state-map
       (kbd "C-<prior>") 'zencoding-expand-line)))
```

So every time `web-mode` or `php-mode` is being loaded, these key bindings will be activated.

**The problem is:** Suppose I have two open buffers, one in the `php-mode` and the other in `web-mode`. When the `web-mode` buffer is the current buffer and I switch to an another buffer which's in `php-mode`, the `web-mode` bindings are still active inside the `php-mode` buffer.

I tried to solve this problem by using `(add-hook 'web-mode-hook [...])` and `(add-hook 'php-mode-hook [...])` instead of setting up the bindings in `eval-after-load`. But that solution doesn't work in this situation.

Any suggestions? I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Evil has the `evil-define-key` macro for defining commands for certain states in a specific keymap only:

```
(evil-define-key 'insert emacs-lisp-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'butterfly
                                             (kbd "<pause>") 'zone)
```

It is able to delay the execution of the binding (by using `eval-after-load` itself) and can also take more than one key-command pair which is a pretty nifty addition.

Comment: Your solution works, I'm grateful for that. Never knew there is such thing as evil-define key. And indeed pretty nifty that you could bind more keycommand pairs to the `evil-define-key`.